Yii2 console help gives double entry for my module
I created a custom module with console command yii gii/module
I get a double entry with console command yii help
screenshot with double entry for module
this is the directory tree

app/modules/vdreports/Module.php
app/modules/vdreports/controllers/DefaultController.php
app/modules/vdreports/views/default/index.php

Module.php
<?php

namespace app\modules\vdreports;

use Yii;
use yii\base\BootstrapInterface;


class Module extends \yii\base\Module implements BootstrapInterface
{

    public function bootstrap($app){
            // print_r('ik ben in bootstrap'.PHP_EOL);
            // var_dump($app->controllerMap);
            foreach ($this->coreCommands() as $id => $command) {
                    if (!isset(Yii::$app->controllerMap[$id])) {
                            Yii::$app->controllerMap[$id] = $command;
                    }
            }
        
        }
        
        public function init()
    {

        parent::init();

        // custom initialization code goes here

    }
        
        public function coreCommands() {
            return [
                'vdreports' => 'app\modules\vdreports\controllers\DefaultController',
            ];
        }
}

I patched it like this
app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/HelpController.php
 protected function validateControllerClass($controllerClass)
    {
        if (class_exists($controllerClass)) {
            $class = new \ReflectionClass($controllerClass);
                        // var_dump($class->isAbstract());
                        // var_dump($class->isSubclassOf('yii\console\Controller'));
            // return !$class->isAbstract() && $class->isSubclassOf('yii\console\Controller');
            return !$class->isAbstract() && $class->isSubclassOf('yii\console\Controller')
              && !strstr($controllerClass,'vdreports'); // 04/08/2024 Marnik : workaround to fix 'yii help' 
        }

        return false;
    }

Now I get a single entry for my module with console command yii help as desired.
This is definitely not the right way.  I don't want to mess up a source file of the yii installation.
Can anybody help?
thanks
Marnik

The double entry is caused by explicitly adding modules's DefaultController to Yii::$app->controllerMap.
If you add the module in your console app config (config/console.php in basic app template, console/config/main.php in advanced app template) it will automatically register all controllers in Module::$controllerNamespace property that extends yii\console\Controller. So you don't need to explicitly add those to Application::$controllerMap property. This is what created vdreports/default entry in your yii help output.
Doing Yii::$app->controllerMap['vdreports'] = 'app\modules\vdreports\controllers\DefaultController'; in your bootstrap() method is what created vdreports entry duplicating already existing vdreports/default entry.
You can simply remove the unnecessary bootstraping to get rid of duplicate entry.
Another option is to move your DefaultController from app\modules\vdreports\controllers namespace to another namespace (and folder) to prevent automatic registration and keep the registration during bootstrap. You can put it for example in app\modules\vdreports\commands namespace. This can be useful if you want to simplify the command.

I implemented "Another option ..." and it works !  Thanks a lot !
I did the first part of your answer when I started the developement of the reporting functionality but I prefered that all my source files and assets would be centralised in a separate subfolder.

However, I found the default generated commands too cumbersome.
